# How to add 2 or more rows in table

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 rows, and 3 buttons in same table, I am trying to add new rows independent to each other. But it outputs the first rows while i click second or third button.
Here is the javascript code for first button and second button respectively.

```
function addRow(dataTable, id) {
  var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(3);
  var colCount = table.rows[5].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[4].cells[i].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("agri").style.visibility = "hidden"; // remove button from newly added row
  }
  document.getElementById("agri").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function addRow1(dataTable, id) {
  var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(4);
  var colCount = table.rows[6].cells.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[5].cells[i].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("promotion").style.visibility = "hidden";  // remove button from newly added row
  }
  document.getElementById("promotion").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

here is some html

```
<input type="button" id="agri" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow(dataTable,this.id)" /> 
<input type="button" id="promotion" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow1(dataTable,this.id)" />
```

Please Help
**Thanks**

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: No, I dnt knw how ro do that and i have only 45 reputation.But I can explain u more.... thanks

Comment: can you explain when 'addRow()' and 'addRow1()' are used ?

Comment: Show us the HTML code. Besides be specific what you have and what you want. You have 3 rows and 3 buttons. where are the buttons? Are they inside the row? That means you have three columns. What did you mean by 'independent to each other' ? Lastly, I guess you want to click a button and a row will appear, is this what you want? If yes then which button will trigger the event?

Comment: it is working properly if i click any button to add row . bt if i click first row and again click second row it will add in first row.(Newly added row donot have button)

Comment: addrow and addrow1 are used when we click 2 buttons to add rows.<input type="button" id="agri" value="Add Row"  onclick="addRow(dataTable,this.id)" />    <input type="button" id="promotion" value="Add Row"  onclick="addRow1(dataTable,this.id)" />

Comment: thanks for you some html, but whe I say to show html I say to show table `I have 3 rows, and 3 buttons in same table` not buttons only

Answer (score 0):

You have errors

not

```
 var table = document.getElementById('dataTable');
```

but, because I think you use  dataTable as variable not string

```
var table = document.getElementById(dataTable);
```

Also put your html code with table

Comment: id of table is also "dataTable" and i am passing variable id as dataTable

Comment: or remove quotes or remove `dataTable` from function variables. also your `id` from function variables not used in function why you need these 2 variables if you don't use it?! Write only `function addRow()` and will be the same.

Comment: @Mr. Shrestha `passing variable`. In function like is it you not pass to function body nothing. The 'dataTable' is string and it will be the same if you will pass to function for example `addRow('test', '1')`, it also will find in document element by id `dataTable ` not `test` because you write `document.getElementById('dataTable');` not `document.getElementById(dataTable);`

Comment: As u say addRow() works, bt actual problem is same as it is

Comment: Put correc problem and will get correct solutions!! As you put problem you will get wrong answers...

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a `row` attribute and change the value of it depending on the elements number

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
  var ii=0;
   function addRow(dataTable, id, type) {
   ii++       
   console.log(id);

     var table = document.getElementById(dataTable);

     var row = table.insertRow(id+parseInt(type));
     var colCount = table.rows[id].cells.length;

     for (var i = 0; i < colCount; i++) {
       var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
       newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[id].cells[i].innerHTML;

   table.rows[id].cells[i].querySelector('input').value=ii.toString();

   if(type==1) 
   table.rows[id].cells[i].style.backgroundColor='red';      
   else
   table.rows[id].cells[i].style.backgroundColor='blue';

     }

   }

   </script>

   <table id="dataTable">
   <tr>1
   <td><input type="button" id="agri" value="Add Row after" onclick="addRow('dataTable',this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,'1')" /></td>
   <td><input type="button" id="agri2" value="Add Row before" onclick="addRow('dataTable',this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex,'-1')" /></td>

   </tr>

   </table>
```

Comment: may be somethink like this `this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex`, because yout `this.id` is not usefully